# How to scroll and view an element below a listview if it takes up the entire screen in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-listview, scrollview

I have a checkout cart ListView in my layout that could possibly take up the entire screen if the user decides to add a lot of items. But the checkout button below the ListView is inaccessible if the listView fills up. Here is a sample layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/cartListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/checkOutButton"
        android:onClick="checkOutButtonClick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button_service"
        android:text="@string/service_findMe_button"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/cartListView"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/widget/NestedScrollView). Your layout should end up looking something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/cartListView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/checkOutButton"
                android:onClick="checkOutButtonClick"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button_service"
                android:text="@string/service_findMe_button"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/cartListView"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Some additional advice:
`ListView` is pretty old school, so I would advice you to use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview).

Comment: Perfect! It works with recycleView! It wasn't working at first with ListView. I don't know why. brilliant solution!